# new item adding to List overriding the previous one

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I am using `List<>` in C# . I want to add values in the `List` . But problem is that first item add successfully but when second item insert the same value ovverride into the first one , example  first item `abc` inserted succefully but when second item `xyz` came it ovveride `abc` to `xyz` and both items shows `xyz`.Here is my code.

```
DataTable dtbl3 = new DataTable();   
List<CartItems> lst = (List<CartItems>)Session["mycart"];
dtbl3 = DAL.Get("Select * from mytable");
List<EmailClass>  lstCstmer = new List<EmailClass>();
for (int j = 0; j < lst.Count; j++)
{          
    emailLst.__EmailcstName = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_name"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstLName = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_LName"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstAddress = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_Addr"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstPhoneNo = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_Phone"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstCellNo = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_CellNo"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstskypId = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_skypeId"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstEmail = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_email"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstCountry = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_country"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstCity = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_City"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstZipcode =Convert.ToInt32( dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_ZipCode"].ToString());
    emailLst.__EmailcstRemarks = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_remarks"].ToString();       
    emailLst._EmailCartProdName = lst[j]._CartProdName;
    emailLst._EmailCartProdPrice = lst[j]._CartProdPrice;
    emailLst._EmailCartProdQnty = lst[j]._CartProdQnty;
    emailLst._EmailCartProdCode = lst[j]._CartProdName;
    emailLst._EmailTotalProdPrice = lst[j]._TotalProdPrice;
    lstCstmer.Add(emailLst);           
}
```

Comment: Where did you initialize `emailLst` instance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659284/c-sharp-list-overwrite-issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156482/why-does-adding-a-new-value-to-list-overwrite-previous-values-in-the-list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156612/ilist-add-overwriting-existing-data, and so on. Search the web for "C# loop list<T> add overwrite" and you'll find plenty of results.

Comment: @Shaharyar emailLst is an instace of Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the same item over and over again, and because it's a reference type all entries in the list point to the same instance of `EmailClass`.

Create a new instance in every loop iteration to fix that:

```
for (int j = 0; j < lst.Count; j++)
{
    emailLst = new EmailClass();

    emailLst.__EmailcstName = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_name"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstLName = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_LName"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstAddress = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_Addr"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstPhoneNo = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_Phone"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstCellNo = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_CellNo"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstskypId = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_skypeId"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstEmail = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_email"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstCountry = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_country"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstCity = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_City"].ToString();
    emailLst.__EmailcstZipcode =Convert.ToInt32( dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_ZipCode"].ToString());
    emailLst.__EmailcstRemarks = dtbl3.Rows[0]["cstm_remarks"].ToString();

    emailLst._EmailCartProdName = lst[j]._CartProdName;
    emailLst._EmailCartProdPrice = lst[j]._CartProdPrice;
    emailLst._EmailCartProdQnty = lst[j]._CartProdQnty;
    emailLst._EmailCartProdCode = lst[j]._CartProdName;
    emailLst._EmailTotalProdPrice = lst[j]._TotalProdPrice;

    lstCstmer.Add(emailLst);

}
```